# Change in structure of graph after update to TensorFlow 0.11

Tags: python, tensorflow

Today, I updated from TensorFlow 0.10 to TensorFlow 0.11. Just to check that the update was successful, I decided to run a MNIST tutorial that I know works fine.

The program did run correctly with TensorFlow 0.11, but I noticed a major change in the way the computational graph looks like. This is how it was [before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OfaQx.png) the update, and this is how it appears [now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5SnW0.png). In the latter picture, I have added a red rectangle to focus attention on the additional nodes.

**Does anyone know why this change occurs, and how I can make the graph look reasonable again?**

Perhaps the following snippet of code will be helpful. It corresponds to the part of the graph that changed appearance.

```
# Cost function 
cross_entropy = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=y_unscal,
                                                    labels=y_plh)
cost = tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy)

# Training op
optimiser = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=1e-4).minimize(cost)
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put that operations in a `variable_scope`.

```
with tf.variable_scope('loss_ops'):
    # Cost function 
    cross_entropy = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=y_unscal,labels=y_plh)
    cost = tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy)

    # Training op
    optimiser = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=1e-4).minimize(cost)
```

In that way a block called `loss_ops` will appear in your graph visualization

Comment: Awesome, thanks @nessuno for the answer! Would anyone also know why behaviour has changed from TensorFlow 0.10 to 0.11?

Comment: I don't know why they changed it, but I think it's better that way: we're forced to wrap operations into named scopes to get good looking graphs. This helps us to reason IMO